# Shorter way to write <Key extends keyof DiscriminatedMap = keyof DiscriminatedMap>?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript2.0, algebraic-data-types

I rely heavily on [ADT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) to model my data. Ergo, I find myself writing `Key extends keyof DiscriminatedMap = keyof DiscriminatedMap` over and over. Is there a shorter way to declare the same?

```
type DiscriminatedUnion<Key extends keyof DiscriminatedMap = keyof DiscriminatedMap> = 
  DiscriminatedMap[Key] & { kind: Key }

type DiscriminatedMap = {
  kindA: { someRecordType: string }
  kindB: { someOtherRecordType: number }
}
```

Comment: You can define alias for keys: `type DiscriminatedMapKeys = keyof DiscriminatedMap;`

Comment: You again! And with a good question again! I wonder what kind of problems you're solving if you're asking such questions!

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko hey friend! I set myself up to develop a backend after developing with [Elm](http://elm-lang.org) for half a year. So in short, everything I had with Elm, I want in my backdend as well :}